# Regex frustration trying to find filename that matches pattern

Tags: php, regex

I suck at regex.  I have a php function that will read through a directory of filenames on my server, and I am trying to pull out filename data from one specific filename, but am failing miserably.  Here is what I have thus far:

```
$file = 'VERSION_3.7.1b.txt';
$VersionNumber = preg_match('#^(VERSION_)[^\s]*\.\.[^\s]+(\.(txt))#', $file);
```

I am trying to have the preg_match only return true for files that begin with 'VERSION_' and end with '.txt.  The stuff in the middle may be any variety of numbers, letters, periods...and that is the part I want to return.  So in this case, I want $VersionNumber to end up set as '3.7.1b'

Other filenames that would return something are like these:

```
VERSION_3.txt  ->  3
VERSION_3.7.txt  ->  3.7
VERSION_3.7e.1.txt  ->  3.7e.1
VERSION_2012.09.13.3.7.1b.txt  ->  2012.09.13.3.7.1b
VERSION_3.7.20120913.txt  ->  3.7.20120913
```

Any regex masters out there that can explain to me if I am even close?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to pass a variable for $matches as well.

I simplified your RegExp. Try this:

```
$file = 'VERSION_3.7.1b.txt';
preg_match('/^VERSION_(.*?)\.txt/', $file, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: Yup.  Also consider preg_filter() to do an array strings and return only their version numbers... `$versionNos = preg_filter($regex, '$1',  $filenames);`